# How to pass parameters to ansible uri module?

Tags: curl, ansible, uri, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to do this in ansible

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/user/admin/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken' --data 'newTokenName=adminToken' --user '{{ jenkins_admin_username }}:{{ jenkins_admin_password }}' -c cookies.txt
```

I'm not sure how to pass these values to uri module, using `ansible 2.9.6`

> newTokenName=adminToken' --user {{ jenkins_admin_username }}:{{
> jenkins_admin_password }}

```
- name: get token
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8080/user/admin/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body: "newTokenName=adminToken=user={{ jenkins_admin_username }}:{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ jenkins_crumb.set_cookie }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html for my answer.

For the first thing `newTokenName=adminToken`, you're looking for the `body` argument:

```yaml
body:
  newTokenName: adminToken
```

It looks like you're passing in basic auth for the credentials, so you're probably looking for the `url_username` and `url_password` arguments for the `uri` module:

```yaml
url_username: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
url_password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
```

Putting all that together, something like this should work:

```yaml
- name: get token
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8080/user/admin/descriptorByName/jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty/generateNewToken"
    method: POST
    return_content: yes
    body:
      newTokenName: adminToken
    url_username: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
    url_password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ jenkins_crumb.set_cookie }}"
```

Comment: Please do consider [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63664463/edit) to use the syntax highlighting for your yaml blocks

Comment: I wasn't previously aware of syntax highlighting in code blocks; good call, thanks @mdaniel